# How do you undo a folder move in Solutions Explorer in Visual Studio with SVN?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, svn

I accidentally moved a very important and large folder from the root project into a sub-folder.  Now when I try to move the folder back, it gives me an error message "Cannot create a file when that file already exists."  How do I move things back?

Additional Information: I am also under SVN and now it wants to start a new log tree.  I just go to win explorer with Tortoise SVN and click commit.  If I just copy and paste the file back to the original folder, SVN wants to delete it on commit.  Wow, I can't believe this little thing is creating a huge mess.

Additional: Well, I deleted the original folder and copy and pasted the new one in and now the commit system isn't working because it's telling me that the folder isn't there (I deleted it so it isn't there).

Answer (score 1):

Are you using any source control plugins like AnkhSVN.

By the sound of it, you've moved the folder which has created it at the new location, and updated the solution file as such, but for some reason, left a copy of the original folder at the original location on the filesystem.

If thats the case you probably need to manually remove it (take a backup first) outside of VS in windows explorer, the you can move it back.

Answer (score 0):

But does the folder, or a file with the same name, exist on the root folder?

If so, I would try to delete it first. Make sure you have the button "Show All Files", on 'Solution Explorer' pressed, in order to visualize all of your tree on VS2008.